# Typescript interface infer generic type from property and apply to other property

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

In typescript I defined an interface like that:

```js
interface MyInterface<T extends (new abstract(...args: any)  => any) = any> {
    component: T;
    componentProps: InstanceType<T>
}
```

having this class:

```js
class TestClass {
   foo?: string
}
```

and using both together like this:

```js
const foo: MyInterface = {
   component: TestClass,
   componentProps: {
     bar: 'baz'
  }
}
```

I would not expect that to compile as `componentProps` should now allow `bar`.

why does `componentProps` not contain the correct type?

Comment: `new abstract` looks very cursed. You need to provide a generic argument. Otherwise the default parameter (`any`) is used and type checks are turned off. Check out [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5ryQHgBVkIAPSEAEwGdkAKECAd3oDp24oBzagLmTgh0ASmTIAvAD4BQ0eJnppAbwBQYsQgD2AWwAOmxuH6EA3GvVa9BiOAAKUTbr7Js1MIKSF0uiEUkqAXxUVBAAbOGpaQgg3AGFwyORVdRhNTQB+fjcoUC5A4K0QN2RUzX4MbEhYRF8wbwhNGGRouITqaXlkjR19QzBjGLB4iOoAGnNkS16bMHtHZy6xUv4AIkg3FfH1ZAAjTlW9gC8V8yCAoA)

Comment: So there is no chance to do it without actually providing the generic argument? Because that is what I wanted; `T` should be taken from what I give to `component`

Comment: You are looking for [this behaviour](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5ryQHgBVkIAPSEAEwGdkQIB3ZACgDp24oBzagLmTgh0ASmQBeAHwCh46eikBvAFDJkCAPYBbAA7r64foQDcKtVt36wABSjrtfZNmphBSQum0QiEkwF8lSggANnDUtIQQzgDCIWHIyqow6uoA-PzOUKBcfgGUEMGcKDAAriAIYMB6yEnqRCTkEFS09ExsHNwOgiLiUl2yXRLMpho6eo1ghgA0w+Zj4DZ2Dk4uZRDunt7TwvylANYg6gwgJjXMEdGx1JPx1cn8AETUWigZWffIvsImQA), right? No, that doesn't work with interfaces. Interfaces can't infer types like functions can infer parameter types.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] without typos; you might want to test it in an IDE to make sure.

Comment: But it's as Behemoth says, this is not possible. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32794 and the linked q/a above.

Comment: Thanks for you answers! Helped me to understand.